# Install rst2man failed for varnish agent [fix]

Tags: package, sudo, varnish, apt-get, ubuntu-server

I'm trying install varnish agent on ubuntu server using virtual box. There is a message in the middle installation process that say "you need rst2man installed to make dist".

When I tried install rst2man using `"sudo apt-get install rst2man"` another message come in :

```
Reading package list....done

Building dependecy tree

Reading state information....done

E: unable to locate package rst2man
```

`"unable to locate package rst2man"` what does it mean ? anyone know ? please help.

---

Problem fix:
I tried to install python-docutils for the rst2man.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**rst2man** is a virtual package,  then you need install **python-docutils** package than provide rst2man and utilities for the documentation of Python modules.

```
sudo apt-get install python-docutils
```

After install this package, try the command:

```
sudo which rst2man
```

Answer (score 9):

`python-docutils` wasn't working for me

I had to install the package `docutils-common`

```
sudo apt-get install docutils-common
```

Answer (score 5):

In case if you installing varnish-agent-2 - after

```
sudo apt-get install python-docutils
```

you should execute again

```
./configure
```

Answer (score 2):

Working on CentOS and likely RHEL as well:

```
yum install python-docutils
```